# is there a difference between "is" and "as" in a PL/SQL procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

When creating a stored procedure, is there a difference between writing

```
Procedure procedureNAME(.....) AS
```

and

```
Procedure procedureNAME(.....) IS
```

Thank you

Comment: No.  There is no difference.  If you look at the documentation, you will see that these are syntactically equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both keywords can be used equivalently. See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CREATE-PROCEDURE-statement.html#GUID-5F84DB47-B5BE-4292-848F-756BF365EC54):

[image]